# Show that topology spaces $I$ and $L$ are homeomorphic.

Tags: general-topology

I am asked to show that $I$ and $L$ are homeomorphic.

My attempt:

Suppose $I$ and $L$ are not homeomorphic. If we remove one point from $I$, we find that $I \backslash \{p\}$ always has two connected components. Since $I$ and $L$ are not homeomorphic, we can find a point $p$ of $L$ such that $L \backslash \{q\}$ has three (or more) connected components. Since $L$ has only two bars, with only point it is impossible to create 3 or more connected components.
Therefore$ $I$ and $L$ are homeomorphic.

I think I have the right intuition but I don't know how to make my proof more rigorous. The most rigorous way I've come up so far is using a proof by contradiction.

PS: Note that $I$ is seen as a straight line and $L$ as two straight lines.

Comment: What exactly is L? Two straight lines put separately, joined at one end, or crossed....?

Comment: Two straight line joined at one end.  @ArcticChar

Comment: Map the origin of $I$ to the join point, the positive numbers in $I$ to one of the rays and the negative numbers to the other.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, your idea for a proof here does not work. As a quick example, we know that $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ are not homeomorphic (even if you haven't proven this yet, it should be intuitively clear) yet the trick of "removing a point and checking the number of connected components" does not work -- in each case we get $1$ connected component. Even trying to remove a line doesn't work, since we can actually separate $\mathbb{R}^3$ into two components using only a line (using [space filling curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve)).

This trick is useful to keep in mind when you want to show that two spaces *aren't* homeomorphic, but tends to fail for this reason when you want to show two spaces *are* homeomorphic. More generally, if you have some invariant, that is useful primarily for *distinguishing* two objects. You can look at their invariants, say "we didn't get the same thing! So my original objects were different!". Invariants are *less* useful for showing that two objects are the same -- it's possible that by some coincidence two objects have the same invariant, even though they aren't the same. Some invariants are "[complete invariants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_set_of_invariants)" in the sense that knowing the invariant means knowing the space (things like the [genus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics)) come to mind), but most of the time we don't have this luxury.

So how, then, do we prove that two spaces *are* the same? Well, our only recourse is to actually *do* it. Can we deform one space into the other? Here is where you want to start using intuition. You might want to think about "rotating" the bent piece of the $\mathsf{L}$ until it's straight and looks like an $\mathsf{l}$.
There are lots of possible homeomorphisms, and writing down any particular one is annoying, but hopefully the above hint is enough to get you going.
It's particularly hard to say more without having a more precise definition of $\mathsf{L}$.

As a tl;dr, and a *big* takeaway for all (ok, most) of math: Invariants are useful for *distinguishing* things. Invariants (unless they are complete) are *not* useful for showing two objects are the same! That said, this isn't a bad thing. Oftentimes it's "easier" to show that two objects are the same than to show they're different. We can just build an isomorphism.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Think of a map from $I$ to $L$ as follows: You start from the top of I and as you move along $I$ map each point of $I$ to $L$ such that by the time you reach half-way through $I$, you reach the starting point of the horizontal line of $L$. Now, continue along $I$, mapping each point to the horizontal line in $L$

This can be easily made rigorous by thinking of $I$ as the $\{0\} \times [0,1]$ and $L$ as $\left(\{0\} \times [0,1]\right) \bigcup \left([0,1] \times \{0\} \right)$ in the plane.